# Is there an alternative to robocopy I can use in my batch file where I can use a wildcard in the path?

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I've done my searching and know I cant use a wildcard in the path with robocopy

I need .csv files from just one directory, but there's many more directories that have .csv files that I do not want, all with different parent directories.

For example:

```
@echo off

set X="1"

set "source=\\Location\To\My\Documents\*\EXPORT\FILE"

set "destination=C:\Users\Public\Documents\Production"

robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" .csv /minage:%X%

exit /b
```

Comment: Let [`for /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) resolve the wildcard `*`: `pushd "\\Location\To\My\Documents" && ((for /D %%I in (*) do robocopy "%%~I\EXPORT\FILE" "%AllUsersProfile%\Documents\Production" "*.csv" /MINAGE:1) & popd)`

Comment: You could even do it using a `for /F` loop, and for even more variety, use the RoboCopy utility itself to resolve the wildcard, `@For /F "Skip=2 Tokens=*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "\\Location\To\My\Documents" Null /L /LEV:2 /NC /NFL /NJH /NJS /NS /S 2^>NUL') Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "%%GEXPORT\FILE" "%Public%\Documents\Production" *.csv /MinAge:1`

Comment: I guess I am a bit confused.  If you only want files from one directory why would you use a wildcard?  If you know what directory you need files from then explicitly use that directory.  Regardless you could use the `/XD` option with `Robocopy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`for /D` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) for resolving the [wildcard `*`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html):

```cmd
@echo off
set "X=1" & rem // (regard the corrected quotation herein!)
set "source_main=\\Location\To\My\Documents"
set "source_sub=EXPORT\FILE"
set "destination=%PUBLIC%\Documents\Production"
set "file_mask=*.csv"

rem // Change into source main directory and resolve UNC path:
pushd "%source%" && (
    rem // Let the following loop resolve any wildcards:
    for /D %%I in ("*") do (
        rem // The following command is executed for every matching sub-directory:
        robocopy "%%~I\%source_sub%" "%destination%" "%file_mask%" /minage:%X%
    )
    rem // Return from source main directory:
    popd
)
exit /B
```